# Нужно ли тире в данном предложении? Секрет убранной двухкомнатной квартиры в том, что она – трёхкомнатная

Tags: пунктуация, тире

Подскажите, нужно ли тире в данном предложении перед "трёхкомнатная"? *Секрет убранной двухкомнатной квартиры в том, что она – трёхкомнатная.*

Comment: Не очень понятное предложение. Лучше что-то вроде: В чём же секрет убранной двухкомнатной квартиры? Теперь она не двухкомнатная, она – трёхкомнатная!

Comment: Это шуточная фраза. Суть в том, что весь хлам в одну комнату сложили)

Comment: Понятно, что задумывалась шутка, но шутка не ясна). Почему трехкомнатная, если в одной комнате хлам? Тогда однокомнатная)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В данном случае тире используется для интонационного подчеркивания и неожиданного присоединения.

> И щуку бросили — в реку (Кр.); Через несколько минут загремели цепи,
> двери отворились, и вошёл — Швабрин (П.)

[Розенталь. Д.Э.](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=91#pp91)